# что значит span в gride?

Tags: css3, css-grid

```css
.myForm {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: [labels] auto [controls] 1fr;
grid-auto-flow: row;
grid-gap: .8em;
background: beige;
padding: 1.2em;
}
.myForm > label {
grid-column: labels;
grid-row: auto;
}
.myForm > input,
.myForm > textarea {
grid-column: controls;
grid-row: auto;
}
.myForm > button {
grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<form class='myForm'>
<label for='customer_name'>Name </label>
<input type='text' name='customer_name' id='customer_name' required>
<label for='email_address'>Email </label>
<input type='email' name='email_address' id='email_address'>
<label for='comments'>Comments</label>
<textarea name='comments' id='comments' maxlength='500'></textarea>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Это означает сколько ячеек, которые охватываются. https://xsltdev.ru/css/grid-column/

Comment: @Denis640Kb вот тут https://xsltdev.ru/css/grid-guide/grid-6/#span указывается grid-row: 1 / span 2; что значит первая строка растянуть на 2 ячейки;  в воем примере нету слеша это значит что в классе .myForm элемент button растянуть на 2 ячейки где бы он не находился ?

Comment: Верно, Вы не задаёте начало ячейки, значит она будет растягиваться с начала элемента.

Comment: @Denis640Kb это наглядно будет так  grid-row: 1 / span 2; верно ? просто не понял что значит начала элемента (под элементом в нашем случае будет button ? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Параметр `span` указывает, сколько ячеек надо объединить. 
В Вашем случае элемент растягивается на 2 ячейки столбцов.

Так как не указано начало отсчёта - счёт идёт от начала элемента `button`, а именно с первого столбца.

Выражение `grid-column: span 2;` эквивалентно `grid-column: 1 / span 2;`

Если вместо 1 вы укажете 2 (`grid-column: 2 / span 2;`), то элемент `button` будет растягиваться на 2 ячейки столбцов начиная со второго столбца.

Параметр `grid-row` объединяет ячейки не столбцов, а строк. 
 Например, имея несколько строк, используя `grid-row: span 2;` Вы можете объединить 2 строки в одну.

Comment: теперь все стало понятно благодарю

Comment: мне кажется надо дополнить ответ при grid-row: span 2 ...